# Update table based on values of column in other 2 table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following tables.

Table 1

```
Id | Data | Values 
1  | rfsd | 23
2  | fghf | 45
3  | rhhh | 23
```

Table 3

```
Id | Data | Values 
1  | rfsd | 23
2  | tfgy | 23
```

Table 2

```
Id | Fields | Counts
1  | 23     |   0 
2  | 45     |   0
```

As you can see, the Counts field is 0. I want to see 'Fields' column in table 2 and compare then with the 'Values' column in table 1 and table 3 and increment the count whenever the value is present in 'Values' field.

The final result should show like this

```
Table 2
Id | Fields | Counts
1  | 23     |   4
2  | 45     |   1
```

This will be the counts since 23 appear four times and 45 appear once in the 'Values' field of table 1 and table 3.

Can someone please let me know how to write a stored procedure for this.

I have implemented something like this.

```
    WITH t1 AS (
              SELECT VALUES, COUNT(*) AS Count2 FROM Table1 GROUP BY VALUES)
UPDATE t2
SET t2.Counts = t1.Count2
FROM Table2 t2
JOIN t1 ON t2.Fields=t1.Values;

WITH t3 AS (SELECT VALUES, COUNT(*) AS Count3 FROM Table3 GROUP BY   VALUES)
UPDATE t2
SET t2.Counts = t3.Count2
FROM
Table2 t2
JOIN t3 ON t2.Fields=t3.Values;
```

When i use this stored procedure, it is updating t2 on basis of t1 table and then overwriting the table t2 by using t3 table.

I want t1 and t3 columns to be updated on t2 table at the same time. Any idea how to correct this stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` to group two tables 1 and 3 together (`UNION ALL` if you want disjoint union, `UNION` if you want to remove duplicate)

```
WITH t13 AS (
    SELECT Id, Data, [Values]
    FROM Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Id, Data, [Values]
    FROM Table3   
), cte AS (
    SELECT 
        [Values], 
        COUNT(*) AS Count2 
    FROM t13
    GROUP BY
        [Values]
)
UPDATE t2
SET Counts = cte.Count2
FROM
    Table2 t2 JOIN cte ON t2.Fields = cte.[Values];
```

Comment: It says, the multi-part identifier "cte.Count2" could not be bound. Anything i misseD ?

Comment: @AduRao Fixed. The table in the JOIN in the UPDATE should be cte instead of t13.

Comment: @AduRao I don't think this is the correct way to ask for upvote. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help.

```
SELECT t2.Id, t2.Fields, COUNT(1) Counts
FROM Table2 t2
    LEFT JOIN Table1 t1 ON t2.Fields = t1.[Values]
    LEFT JOIN Table3 t3 ON t2.Fields = t3.[Values]
GROUP BY t2.Id, t2.Fields
```

If you need to update the Table2, use the following:-

```
WITH Results AS (
    SELECT t2.Id, COUNT(1) Counts
    FROM Table2 t2
       LEFT JOIN Table1 t1 ON t2.Fields = t1.[Values]
       LEFT JOIN Table3 t3 ON t2.Fields = t3.[Values]
    GROUP BY t2.Id
)
UPDATE t
SET Counts = r.Counts
FROM Table2 t
    JOIN Results r ON t.Id = r.Id;
```